# Does a redundant where predicate in a SQL query affect performance?

Tags: sql

Consider a query like:

```
select *
from t
where a = 5 and (a = 5 and b = 7)
```

Does the redundant predicate `a = 5` affect the performance of the query. I believe not, but I am being told otherwise (yes, I know that it depends on the DBMS but just assume it's some enterprise-y DBMS like SQL Server, DB2 or Oracle).

Comment: That first condition is pointless, it will always be true under the second condition as well.

Comment: I would suggest loooking at your execution plan oe Explain plan to see if there are differnces in how the optimizer handles. But personally I would take out the redunant clause for maintenance reasons anyway.

Comment: The only way this query makes sense to me is if the where clause is like `where a = 5 or (a = 5 and b = 7)
`

Comment: @Ozair Kafray: I didn't ask whether or not the query makes sense. I asked if performance is affected.

Comment: @Dustin Laine: I didn't ask if the first predicate is pointless or not (I'm already aware of that since I said "redundant" in the title and body of my post). I asked if performance is affected by the, to use your word, "pointless" predicate in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Dustin, it's likely this is coming from some sort of dynamic SQL or prepared statement. No one would hand-code this. The issue is whether it is a problem when it comes up.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: You are correct.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to quote the following from [The Law of Leaky Abstractions by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)

> The SQL language is meant to abstract
>   away the procedural steps that are
>   needed to query a database, instead
>   allowing you to define merely what you
>   want and let the database figure out
>   the procedural steps to query it. But
>   in some cases, certain SQL queries are
>   thousands of times slower than other
>   logically equivalent queries. A famous
>   example of this is that **some SQL
>   servers are dramatically faster if you
>   specify "where a=b and b=c and a=c"
>   than if you only specify "where a=b
>   and b=c" even though the result set is
>   the same.** You're not supposed to have
>   to care about the procedure, only the
>   specification. But sometimes the
>   abstraction leaks and causes horrible
>   performance and you have to break out
>   the query plan analyzer and study what
>   it did wrong, and figure out how to
>   make your query run faster.

Answer (score 5):

The answer would normally be no, the redundant clause does not affect performance. Of course being a programmer you can use evidence to prove it one way or the other (unlike the person who will repeat their myths as fact).

Just open up your database of choice, enter your query with and without the redundent clause, then ask your database to `explain` both queries.

For example in SQL Server Management Studio (MS SQL Server) open a query window, enter your query and then right click and select "Display estimated executation plan" (or you can select an option to display the actual plan after the query is run).

Comment: +1, the reason that it doesn't affect performance is that your DBA does/should do short circuit evaluation of the where clause (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and will stop testing as soon as the result is a definite `true` or `false`

Comment: @Johan: How does short-circuiting help here? Naive short-circuiting on `a == 5 && a == 5 && b == 7` for some row where `a == 5` is true would evaluate the truth of `a == 5` twice.

Comment: @Fred, read the link, and come back when you **understand** what `short circuit evaluation` is. *hint it's **not** about doing things twice*

Comment: @Johan: Don't patronize me. Short-circuiting evaluation stops evaluating a boolean expression with multiple predicates as soon as it can (so `p1 && p2` doesn't evaluate `p2` if `p1` is false and `p1 || p2` doesn't evaluate `p2` if `p1` is true). Come back when __you__ understand short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @Fred, and that's how it speeds things up. The second test never evaluates. And if it is a constant expression the query optimizer will strip it out before transcribing the query into byte code *(or whatever the query executioner groks)*